# Pentaho-spoon Reading text file

Tags: text-files, textinput, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

We have a text file with multiple fields and it is being used in different transformations. When I do 'Get Fields' in Text File Input, I get fields as follows:

[image]

I don't need all these fields for the next step so I kept only required fields(i.e. 1st, 3rd,18th and 19th) as follows and removed other fields in Text File Input as there are '?' per parameter in the next step.

[image]

But it is picking the value of initial fields only.
I even tried using 'Position' as per the file, but no luck. Can anyone please tell me what I am missing here?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Text File Input** reads the columns sequentially even though you specify certain column names in the **Fields** tab.

Select all the fields in the Fields tab of the **Text File Input** and use **Select Values** as the next step and there select only the required fields.